# How to benchmark different text processing commands and find out the fastest?

Tags: text-processing, performance

I have a text file and I need to process it according to some rules. To accomplish the task I can use multiple ways. For example I can use the linux command `cut`, `paste`, `sed`, `awk` etc. There are multiple ways to write the command used by a single utility. I want to know how can I test which choice is better. Thanks.

Comment: Note that for benchmarking purposes you probably better redirect the output to `/dev/null` in order to avoid the pure text processing performances from being contaminated with the displaying of text, which in some cases is the main time-consuming part of the processing and is more sensitive to resources availability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time).
That should give you all the information you need.

Comment: Thank you! A few minutes after I posted my question I found this time utility. I'll take a look.